# $ \lim_{x\to 0,y\to0} \frac{\ln {(3+2x^4 + 2y^4 + x^3y^2 + x^4y + xy^4)} - \sqrt[3]{ (1+6x^4+6y^4-3x^2y^2} +\ln(\frac{e}{3}))} {\arctan (x^4 +y^4)}$

Tags: analysis

How to find this limit?

$$ \lim_{x\to 0,y\to0} \frac{\ln {(3+2x^4 + 2y^4 + x^3y^2 + x^4y + xy^4)} - \sqrt[3]{ (1+6x^4+6y^4-3x^2y^2} +\ln(\frac{e}{3}))} {\arctan (x^4 +y^4)}$$

Firstly, I implied equivalence for denominator, then used transition to the polar system, after that i got infinity. I think, I'm supposed to be wrong. Please, help me understand the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write y=mx and by substitution of y in your equation you get an expression variables m and x. 
Then you make x tend to 0. if limit exits the results must be independent of m. Otherwise the limit value will be dependent of direction m.  What actually does not happen therefore the value of your function at (0,0) is inexistent.

Comment: Note you can only substitute $y=mx$ to try to show that a limit is nonexistent; Showing that the limit converges to the same value for all substitutions $y=mx$ does NOT imply the limit converges. An example of this is $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$